# Creating Jar file - doesn't work on other computers

Tags: java, jar, executable, runnable

I'm trying to package my program into a JAR file so it can be used on multiple computers.

My program is composed of `start.java`, `userinterface.java` and `writer.java`.

The program, written in Eclipse, works perfectly on my computer. When exported, it will work on my computer but cause the following error on other computers:

`"Could not find the main class: start. Program will exit".`

Again, my program runs fine on my computer when I double click on it.

I've tried creating the JAR file via command prompt, and my Manifest file is correct. What is happening?

Comment: Maybe they have a JVM with a lower version than the one you used to compile?

Comment: Well, I've attached the file to my main post, perhaps you'd care to give it a go?

Comment: If you compiled the program using for example JDK 6, then the program won't be launched by JRE 5. @GuillaumePolet is right: what versions do you use to compile and then run on the other machine ?

Comment: OK, I get the same result as your colleagues. I have a JVM 6 but you have compiled using a JVM 7. Either make them upgrade to JVM 7. Or compile using -target 6

Comment: Maybe, it is not enough memory when running it with the JVM from that computer. It happens a lot in my case. Set the VM arguments for `-Xms` and `-Xmx` when running on that computer. This only applies if the JVM is the same major version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very strange bug which I've also encountered.

Assuming you are using `JRE 1.7`, 
The only fix I found to this problem was to change the project's `JRE` version from `1.7` down to `1.6`.

**Edit:** I've also encountered this error on computers with JVM 7.

Comment: Well, sometimes I would compile projects with `JRE 1.7` and they would work fine, while some other projects encountered the same problem - even though I've tried all of these jars on computers with JVM 7.

Comment: I tried using the -target 6 flag but I get the error: target release 6 conflicts with default source release 1.7. How do I address this? Thank you

Comment: @user1147964 I've used Eclipse to do this, so I am not sure what is the command-line equivalent. I suggest you try doing that using Eclipse.

Comment: I just did it using eclipse and it works on the other computer - thanks for the help.
Problem is that 1.6 doesn't support HTML in JComponents which is a bit irritating - guess I'll have to force them to update.

Comment: @user1147964 You're welcome. Please mark this as the correct answer if it solved your problem. ^^

Comment: *"1.6 doesn't support HTML in JComponents"* Of course it does!  Swing supported HTML in styled dcouments (`JLabel`, `JEditorPane` ..) since 1.2, when they were first introduced.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you try to specify a class file from the **default package** for the `Main-Class` attribute. JAR files and default packages don't really mix well. I would advise to put your whole project into a simple package (as far as I saw from the attached JAR file you use only the default package).

Also, try to adopt to the [common Java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) (its hard to tell what is a class and first I thought there is some package-specific error, i.e., use `Start` instead of `start` as a classname).

Another common issue is that the last line of the `MANIFEST.MF` file is uninterpreted, as stated [in the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html):

> **Warning:**
>
> The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.